# Is this 'tip' about the distinct function outdated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

So according to [this website](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/12/sql-distinct-group-by.aspx) circa 2007, we should not use `distinct` as a function, i.e. don't do something like

```
select distinct(employeeID), salary
from salaryhist
```

Is that still true? I'm having a  hard time figuring it out with queries

Comment: I don't understand, do you WANT to use that syntax, even though it's not going to work the way that form implies? Or do you want your query to treat employeeId distinctly but not salary? If the latter, there are ways to retun one row per employee by picking which salary to show (e.g. Max, latest, earliest, etc). As written the query doesn't really make sense... which salary should be returned if you have employeeId = 1, salary = 20k and employeeId = 1, salary = 25k?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I see what you mean. Well my boss used it like the above shows, I think he was mistaken then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISTINCT is ***not*** a function. It never was (and probably never will)

The expression `select distinct (employeeID)` is not a function call.

It's the keyword `select` followed by the keyowrd `distinct` followed by the column expression `(employeeID)`.

To make things more clear, the following three things are identical:

- `select distinct employeeID, (salary)`
- `select distinct (employeeID), (salary)`
- `select distinct employeeID, salary`

All are the same because `employeeID` and `(employeeID)` are the same thing: a reference to a column.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. About ID, Hey that was a nice song btw

Answer (score 0):

you have to get better result compare to your query,

select employeeID, sum(salary) from salaryhist group by employeeID